# Android Manifest Editor not working properly

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

Ubuntu 11.10   ADT 16.01   Java 6  Eclipse Java EE Indigo SR1 - All latest release following android dev requirements.

I am just starting to learn coding for android and got to a tutorial on switching Activities. Using the New project android template, I made another test activity class identical to the first except for name.

```
package com.test.SwitchActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SwitchActivityActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I use the Menifest editor edit the AndroidManifest.xml file - add button for the Application Node, the listbox is empty. All the tutorials I have found are populated with xml tag choices. Now, I can add the xml data manually - it is no problem. What is driving me nuts is not being able to figure out why it does not work for me as it is supposed to work. I don't find other people having the issue and I have re-installed everything at least once before coming here to post another question.

I just want to finish the tutorial and switch between two activities.

Here is a screenshot of what I describe. Anyone have any ideas as to why it does not work?
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fwfbz.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create another activity

1. Create a new class "myactivity.java" that extends the Activity
2. Create android xml file with your UI items in it lets call it exampleactivity.xml (it should be in small letters with .xml extension and should be saved in res/layout folder).
3. In myactivity.java add the following method (same as above except exampleactivity replaced main)

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.exampleactivity);
   }
           }
4. create a button changeactivity in SwitchActivityActivity and initialize it in onCreate method of SwitchActivityActivity  via

   changeactivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newActivityButton);
5. create the following in onCreate method of SwitchActivityActivity

   changeactivity.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    Intent i;
    public void onClick(View v) {
    i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DEFAULT);
    i.setClass(SwitchActivityActivity.this, myactivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
   }
   });
6. In the main.xml create a button and give the button id by

   android:id="@+id/newActivityButton"
7. Finally add the following in AndroidManifest file after the SwitchActivityActivity activity tag

compile and run it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that I didnt mention what I was trying to do. I want to switch from one activity to another. According to the tutorials I read, both activities have to be (registered?) in the AndroidManifest.xml file. I have not gotten to the point of actually writing anything to accomplish the switch - by code, button or whatever. IS the empty box I show in the screenshot not supposed to be populated with tag choices? If so, why does this not work?

Comment: I give up. There is no way anyone is going to really read what I am asking here. it does not really matter in the copy and paste world.